# How to set masked pandas DataFrame column to column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I set certain cells in a column to a list from a list of lists where the list of lists has the same length as the number of cells?

When running the portion I tried, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an
> ndarray

My desired DataFrame, as defined explicitly below with `desired` looks like this:

```
   include   array
0     True  [1, 2]
1    False     NaN
2    False     NaN
3     True  [3, 4]
4    False     NaN
```

Code tried:

```py
import pandas as pd

# This is what I tried
a = pd.DataFrame({'include': [True, False, False, True, False]})
a.loc[a['include'], 'array'] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

# This is what I want
desired = pd.DataFrame({'include': [True, False, False, True, False],
                        'array': [[1, 2], np.nan, np.nan, [3, 4], np.nan]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want to do, but you can cast it to a `pandas.Series` and allign the indices:

```
a.loc[a['include'], 'array'] = pd.Series([[1, 2], [3, 4]], index=[0, 3])

print(a)
   include   array
0     True  [1, 2]
1    False     NaN
2    False     NaN
3     True  [3, 4]
4    False     NaN
```

To keep the assign of the index general and not hard coded, use:

```
a.loc[a['include'], 'array'] = pd.Series([[1, 2], [3, 4]], a[a['include']].index)
```